# Spring Security redirect to previous page after successful registering on secuser and auto login

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have used spring security plugin in my Grails 2.4.5 application. I have authentication before user makes online payment. If user is not logged in, Spring Security asks for login before payment, and if user is not having account then he is made to register and made to auto login. During this I need previous URL. How to get previous url after registering and auto login in Grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can auto redirect to previous page with parameters after successful registration and login, following is the controller code to achieve that,

```
      println "previous url:"+request.getHeader('referer')
      redirect(uri: request.getHeader('referer') )
```

Comment: No @nitin Dhomse  i guess we cannot do this way because i have parameters along with controller and action. I need complete previous url with hidden parameters in the form so that i can direct execute that uri.

Comment: Did you try 

request.requestURI + '?' + request.queryString